# Taxes for retired American expat in Egypt?

Tags: taxes, us-citizens, tax-treaties, tax-deductions, egypt

I'm not in Egypt currently; I'm just researching the implications of many possible countries.

NO plans of working: my retirement income¹ is more than enough to live on in many countries.

I've found several web pages, some say nothing and the others assume working in Egypt.  So I’m wondering whether there are exemptions for pensions or SS like some countries have, or whether they tax the parts USA doesn't (USA says **part** of my SS in nontaxable).  Also, under the treaty, do we file US first and have Egypt tax the difference, or vice versa?  (Or is that a question for the finance stack?)

¹SS, pensions, interest; all from USA.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should probably be moved to money@se

Comment: I am going to ask over there, but I don't expect any expats living in Egypt to see it!  https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/152821/taxes-for-retired-american-expat-in-egypt